# effects of weak reference in java

Tags: java

I have one doubt. I read in one of the tutorial , that if key of hashmap is of weakreference type , then value corresponding to that key is liable for garbbage collection. Kindly tell , suppose my hashmap is of kind HashMap, its normal hashmap , then when will the object will be liable for GC. Suppose the method in which i am creating the hashmap contains one infinite loop,eg:

```
public void f(){
Map<String,Object> abc = new HashMap<Sring,Object>;
while(true){
//some operation 
}

}
```

Now , if instead of String as key , i am using some weak key, then what will be the effect?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't explicitly using weak references, you don't need to worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

If you had

```
HashMap<WeakReference<SomeType>, Object> map = ...;
```

Then only the object in the `WeakReference` object would be eligible for garbage collection, not the `WeakReference` object itself.

With any `HashMap`, the keys will only become eligible for garbage collection when the `HashMap` containing them and all other objects referencing them become unreachable.